# Installing Age of Empires II using PlayOnLinux doesn't work?

Tags: games

I have tried installing age of empires 2 using PlayOnLinux, the installation appeared to go fine but when I try and open the game it says there is a serious fault.

The error report is below, unfortunately this doesn't mean alot to me, I was wondering if you could help, a) By highlighting the problem and b) by suggesting a solution.

Many Thanks

> Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0xffffffff in 32-bit code (0x0040aaad).
>
> Register dump:
>
> > CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
> >      EIP:0040aaad ESP:0033fd00 EBP:0033fde4 EFLAGS:00010293(  R- --  I S -A- -C)
> >      EAX:00000001 EBX:bde88d9d ECX:00000067 EDX:00400000
> >      ESI:7b867c00 EDI:00400000
>
> Stack dump:
>
> > 0x0033fd00:00410fed 00000000 00400000 00000067
> >     0x0033fd10:0041ab90 00130d8a 7b895848 7bc483b1
> >     0x0033fd20:0044c800 00000002 0044bdd0 7bca4e6c
> >     0x0033fd30:7bc3590f 00000800 00000094 00000005
> >     0x0033fd40:00000000 00000893 00000002 76726553
> >     0x0033fd50:20656369 6b636150 00003420 00000800
>
> Backtrace:
>
> > =>0 0x0040aaad in empires2 (+0xaaad) (0x0033fde4)
> >       1 0x0041ace2 in empires2 (+0x1ace1) (0x0033fe70)
> >       2 0x7b85ac0c call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0033fe88)
> >       3 0x7b85e13b in kernel32 (+0x4e13a) (0x0033fec8)
> >       4 0x7bc714f0 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0033fed8)
> >       5 0x7bc7172d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x0033ffa8)
> >       6 0x7bc714ce RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0033ffc8)
> >       7 0x7bc4c30e in ntdll (+0x3c30d) (0x0033ffe8)
> >     0x0040aaad: pop %ss
>
> Modules:
>
> > Module    Address         Debug info  Name (51 modules)
> >     PE    400000-  44b000   Export          empires2
> >     PE  10000000-1000c000   Deferred        drvmgt
> >     ELF 35cae000-35d24000   Deferred        rpcrt4
> >       -PE  35cc0000-35d24000   \               rpcrt4
> >     ELF 68000000-68022000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
> >     ELF 68022000-681c7000   Deferred        libc.so.6
> >     ELF 681c7000-681cc000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
> >     ELF 681cc000-681f8000   Deferred        libm.so.6
> >     ELF 681f8000-68201000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
> >     ELF 68201000-6821b000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
> >     ELF 6821b000-68228000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
> >     ELF 68228000-68366000   Deferred        user32
> >       -PE  68240000-68366000   \               user32
> >     ELF 68366000-68421000   Deferred        gdi32
> >       -PE  68370000-68421000   \               gdi32
> >     ELF 68421000-68481000   Deferred        advapi32
> >       -PE  68430000-68481000   \               advapi32
> >     ELF 68481000-68499000   Deferred        version
> >       -PE  68490000-68499000   \               version
> >     ELF 68499000-68533000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
> >     ELF 68533000-68549000   Deferred        libz.so.1
> >     ELF 68549000-685db000   Deferred        winex11
> >       -PE  68550000-685db000   \               winex11
> >     ELF 685db000-685e4000   Deferred        libsm.so.6
> >     ELF 685e4000-685fe000   Deferred        libice.so.6
> >     ELF 685fe000-68610000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
> >     ELF 68610000-68744000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
> >     ELF 68744000-6874a000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
> >     ELF 6874a000-68751000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
> >     ELF 68751000-68755000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
> >     ELF 68755000-6875b000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
> >     ELF 6875b000-68765000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
> >     ELF 68765000-6876e000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
> >     ELF 6876e000-68772000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
> >     ELF 68772000-68782000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
> >     ELF 68782000-687b6000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
> >     ELF 687b6000-687e0000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
> >     ELF 687e0000-687eb000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
> >     ELF 687eb000-687f1000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
> >     ELF 6f102000-6f10e000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
> >     ELF 7194d000-7196e000   Deferred        imm32
> >       -PE  71950000-7196e000   \               imm32
> >     ELF 72c76000-72db7000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
> >     ELF 75d65000-75d86000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
> >     ELF 79223000-79227000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
> >     ELF 7b800000-7b8f5000   Dwarf           kernel32
> >       -PE  7b810000-7b8f5000   \               kernel32
> >     ELF 7bc00000-7bcc1000   Dwarf           ntdll
> >       -PE  7bc10000-7bcc1000   \               ntdll
> >     ELF 7bf00000-7bf03000   Deferred        
> >     ELF 7c708000-7c723000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
>
> Threads:
>
> > process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
> >     00000008 (D) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Age of Empires II\empires2.exe
> >         00000009    0 <==
> >     0000000e services.exe
> >         00000039    0
> >         00000038    0
> >         0000001f    0
> >         00000019    0
> >         00000018    0
> >         00000017    0
> >         00000015    0
> >         00000010    0
> >         0000000f    0
> >     00000012 winedevice.exe
> >         0000001e    0
> >         0000001a    0
> >         00000014    0
> >         00000013    0
> >     0000001b plugplay.exe
> >         00000021    0
> >         0000001d    0
> >         0000001c    0
> >     00000024 explorer.exe
> >         00000025    0
> >     00000035 winedevice.exe
> >         0000003a    0
> >         00000037    0
> >         00000036    0
>
> System information:
>
> > Wine build: wine-1.4-rc1
> >         Platform: i386
> >         Host system: Linux
> >         Host version: 3.2.0-24-generic

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing it wants you to put the CD in the drive.

If it is in the drive and the problem repeats, try to find a no-CD crack and apply it to the application directory (open PlayOnLinux, right-click over the AOE II entry, choose Open the application's directory).

It's three months old and you may have given up about it, but just in case someone stumbles upon...